# Play ringtone from the application only for a specific time period

Tags: android, audio

I need to play a ringtone from a application which I am able to achieve. Now, I want to play the ringtone only for the specific duration based on the user input.

If user selects 60sec, the audio should play 60sec  only and then stop.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Cheers,
Prateek

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course. Use [TimerTask](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) to stop playback after the given period of time.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, timertask works well for this.  Here's the code I use and it works:

```
long ringDelay = 3500;
Uri notification = RingtoneManager
                           .getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM);
final Ringtone alarmRingtone = RingtoneManager
                   .getRingtone(getApplicationContext(), notification);
alarmRingtone.play();
TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        alarmRingtone.stop();
    }
};
Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.schedule(task, ringDelay);
```